# jquery tab for multiple users and custom data application

Tags: php, jquery

I had been coding the font end of an app purely using jquery, but I seem like I have to pick one back-end language like php because in the end it would be a multiple users application.

my question is how to use jquery tab but its content are manipulated by user, like the example below

example : http://www.mytinytodo.net/demo/

Answer (score 0):

You can do an ajax call on the tab clicks depending upon the users. Either you can get the contents from the backend, or you can get a confirmation flag that what content you need to display for that tab and display the content accordingly.

Comment: Ajax calls are made from front-end only. For example you just make an ajax call on the tabs click, and send some parameters like tab id and user information to the back-end. Manipulate the logic on what you want to display in this tab for this particular user and send a flag or data and after you get a response from the Ajax call, display that data in the tab

for more info on Ajax : http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ visit here

Comment: if security is not a concern, you can just put different contents for different users and just hide/show them for whatever user you want to show or hide.